# Many ads pages are opening on Firefox while navigating

Tags: firefox, malware

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and Firefox 24.
Lately I'm having this issue on Firefox, some ads pages like "thelotter" are opening in new tab while visiting some sites. 
I have many addons that blocks ads, pop-ups and other stuff, like "Noscript", ghostery, adblock etc... but still the open, so I thought that it could be due to some malware I got on the web.

The question is: is it possible that I have some malware or anything like that on my ubuntu? How can I check it? And how can I solve the problem?

I also tried to remove firefox and its folder in /home and reinstalled it but same thing.

What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: What exact folder did you remove in `/home`? I'd say you've installed a malicious Firefox addon of some sort. Removing the Firefox user profile should fix that. Are other browsers also affected?

Comment: Are you using the Firefox synchronization functionality to synch your Ubuntu Firefox with the Windows one? I had a problem like that with my Google Chrome.

Comment: @gertvdijkI removed /home/.mozilla, Well I usually use only trusted addons, it effects only firefox. I will try to reset the user profile thanks.

Comment: @Zignd I also use xmarks to synchronize bookmarks so maybe it is the problem I don't know

Comment: @Frank I installed once an application on Windows and forgot to uncheck one of that annoying toolbar option, so it installed on my Windows Google Chrome and when a booted my Ubuntu the Google Chrome started to synch and I got an almost impossible to remove toolbar on it. The solution was to reset the browser options, on GC it's in the bottom of the configuration page.

Comment: ok no it's not my problem, I finally found the addons causing this very annoying behaviour. It was this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/web-search-optimizer/, it has ads but lets user to decide wether to allow it, but even if you does not allow ads they are there waiting for you. Solved the problem by removing that addon

Comment: Congradulations, you are the first person to ever download and install malware to an Ubuntu install... Good job!

Comment: While I **don't** think it's related you still might want to [drop ghostery](http://venturebeat.com/2012/07/31/ghostery-a-web-tracking-blocker-that-actually-helps-the-ad-industry/)